# Was asked to create efi partition as well as bios grub partition while manually formatting whole drive in Ubuntu 22.04 installation. Is it normal?

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I was running Windows 10 fresh on my pc. It was a uefi system (i think but long ago i turned secure boot off and turned on legacy bios mode in my bios settings.) I had installed and removed and reinstalled Ubuntu and several linux distros several times, sometime dual booting with windows etc. This time i wanted to fully format my hdd and install fresh Ubuntu 22.04. while installing i chose something else in the partitioning, and deleted all existing partitions, created a new partition table and created a 8gb swap and the rest I allocated to '/'. Then i was asked to create an efi partition as i was warned otherwise system might not boot. I did so but then again I was asked to flag a new partition as biosgrub. And then i was able to install. Shouldn't just efi be used for uefi based systems, or is both necessary? Earlier before i never had to create both. Also although i created 4 partions 2 separate free spaces were left, one 764 kb and on 1 mb. I couldn't include them in any partion however i tried. Is this normal?

Answer (score 2):

### Partitions to make booting possible

- With a GUID partition table a small partition with the **bios_grub** flag is necessary to boot in BIOS mode (alias CSM alias legacy mode).
- An **EFI system partition** (usually with FAT32 file system) is necessary to boot in UEFI mode.

If I remember correctly from my installations, Ubuntu 22.04 LTS asks for both when installing in BIOS mode, which makes it easier, if you want to switch between boot modes later on, upgrade to UEFI mode, but in principle only one of those partitions is necessary (one for each boot mode).

But when installing in UEFI mode, only the EFI system partition is created (no bios_grub partition), which was kindly remarked by user68186.

See this link: [help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace).

### Tiny unallocated fragments on the drive

And yes, it happens rather often that tiny fragments are left before, between and after partitions. The partitions are managed (read and written) more efficiently, when they are aligned to MiB (mibibyte) positions.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu 22.04 in a QEMU VM with GPT in UEFI mode with the default install (**Not** Something Else). The installation process did not create any **bios_grub** partition. The virtual disk only has two partitions, 1. ESP and 2. `/`. I would like to up vote this answer, but I couldn't find the evidence of the Ubuntu 22.04 installation process creating both ESP and bios_grub partitions on the same computer by default.

Comment: @user68186, Thanks for the heads up. Then it seems to want or create an extra partition only when booting in BIOS mode (it creates an EFI system partition). This is logical, today BIOS mode is a corner case for old chaps (like me) who want to keep old computers alive. So the Ubuntu developers are focusing on UEFI mode. Anyway, I will modify my answer according to your findings.

Comment: Your comment seems to say: If I have GPT and install Ubuntu 22.04 in BIOS/Legacy mode, then the installation will create both ESP and bios_grub partitions. I have not tested this. If you are sure of this specific set of conditions, please add this to your answer.

Comment: @user68186 In order to be sure I have to make a fresh installation. I intend to do that, but cannot do it at once ...

Comment: I did the test and you are right! I created a virtual disk with GPT. Then I installed Ubuntu 22.04 in BIOS mode on that disk using a VM that has BIOS (not UEFI). The installation process created three partitons: 1. bios_grub, 2. ESP, and 3. `/`. I am up voting your answer.

Comment: Exactly ^^^ . The ESP is there in case you change your mind later. And if done right - there's a famous Q&A here - by installing both bootloaders it can boot either way.

Comment: @ChanganAuto, There is another and new tool that makes it easy to get a [portable] drive that can boot either way. See this link to the following Ubuntu Forum link: [Ubuntu Server amd64 compressed image (when extracted) boots in UEFI and BIOS mode](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2474692).

Comment: @sudodus Thanks. Great work.

Comment: Thanks you guys for your awesome responses, btw I too wanted to clear the confusion and did a fresh install without using "something else" and used erase disk and install ubuntu, now I got 3 partitions, biosgrub, efi and /.

Comment: @SrijanMukherjee, I conclude that your installed Ubuntu system works too, so congratulations :-)